# Which is the nominative case in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

> Die Regierung werde Studentendarlehen verfügbar machen für Studenten, die studieren wollen....

Should the relative pronoun after *Studenten* be *den* because *die Regierung* is nominative?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your reasoning why the relative pronoun should be "den"?

Comment: I also don't understand why you think of "den", it's clearly "die Studenten, die". Even if it's relate to "Regierung", it'd be "die": "die Regierung, die"

Answer (score 2):

The relative pronouns gets the case from the function the entity has in the relative sentence. In this case it is subject because it is the students that study.Case configuration in the main sentence has absolutely no influence on it at all because it is a different verb.

Answer (score -1):

The nominative in the main sentence is "Die Regierung" (who/wer?), and an object is "Studenten". Hence, the pronoun for the relative sentence is "die (Studenten)". If it was for "Regierung", the verb would have the wrong singluar/plural mode.

Note, however, that there is a rule which nearly all native German speakers miss: "die" cannot be pronoun for an object, it should read "welche".

Comment: If that rule ever existed, it is dead by now. You say it yourself.